# get query result displayed in a table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble on figuring out how to display query results in a table. The html form has a drop down menu that allows selecting an institution name. The table should display the persons that belong to the institution. When I execute the code via submit button, the query result from pgsql is displayed on the php page. The Json is displayed basically. I should get the result of the query displayed in a table that should appear on the html page.
I have been told to use ajaxsubmit() but I am unsure on how to adapt my code below. Help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

   //////////////////////////////////////
  // Displays insitution names in Drop Down Menu

        //Getting the selector and running the code when clicked
        $('#selinstit').click(function(e){
                 //Getting the JSON object, after it arrives the code inside
               //function(dataI) is run, dataI is the recieved object
               $.getJSON('http://localhost/listinstitutions.php',function(dataI){
                            //loop row by row in the json, key is an index and val the row
                            var items = [];  //array
                          $.each(dataI, function(key, val) {
                            //add institution name to <option>  
                            items.push('<option>' + val['Iname'] + '</option>');
                        });//end each
                        //concatenate all html
                        htmlStr=items.join('');
                        console.log(htmlStr);
                        //append code
                        $('option#in').after(htmlStr);
                });//end getJSON
        });//end cluck


    ///////////////////////////////
   // Displays persons form an institution in a table

     $( "$subinst" ).button().click(function( event ) {
     //console.log($(this)); // for Firebug    
     $.getJSON('http://localhost/SelectPersonsBasedOnInstitution.php',function(data){   // I make an AJAX call here
     //console.log($(this)[0].url); // for Firebug   check what url I get here
                            //loop row by row in the json, key is an index and val the row
                            var items = [];  //array
                          $.each(data, function(key, val) {

                        //add table rows
                            items.push('<tr border=1><td>' + val['Pfirstname'] + '</td><td>' + val['Plastname'] + '</td><td><a mailto:=" ' + val['Pemail'] + ' " >' + val['Pemail'] + '</a></td></tr>');
                        });//end each
                        //concatenate all html
                    htmlStr=items.join('');

                        //append code
                        $('#instito').after(htmlStr);
                });//end getJSON
      event.preventDefault();
      });


    //// to send query to php file: for slect institution
    $("#subinst").click(function() {

    var url = "http://localhost/SelectPersonsBasedOnInstitution.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#myForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });



}); //end ready

</script>

</head>   

<body>

<form id="myForm" action="SelectPersonsBasedOnInstitution.php" method="post">
Select persons from an institution:
<br>                                            
<tr>
 <td>
   <select id="selinstit" name="instit">
   <option id="in">Select</option>                       
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
   <input type="submit" id="subinst" value="Submit" /> 
 </td>
</tr>

</form>

   <table frame="border" id="instito">
   </table>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP code for SelectPersonsBasedOnInstitution.php

```
<?php


//////////
// part 1: get information from the html form
ini_set('display_errors', 1);                                      
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value){
 $$key=$value;  
}

// part2: prepare SQL query from input
$sqlquery= sprintf('SELECT "Pfirstname", "Plastname", "Pemail" FROM "PERSON"
LEFT JOIN "INSTITUTION" ON
"PERSON"."Pinstitution"="INSTITUTION"."Iinstitution"
WHERE "Iname" = \'%s\'',$instit);
//echo $sqlquery;


/////////
// part3: send query
$dbh = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=mydv user=***password=***");
$sql=  $sqlquery;
$result = pg_query($dbh,$sql);
$myarray = pg_fetch_all($result);

$jsontext = json_encode($myarray);
echo($jsontext);

?>
```

Comment: You can simply use `$.getJSON('/listinstitutions.php'...`

Comment: Yes indeed, but this does not solve the issue I have. Thx though.

Comment: Does your PHP-code work without involvment of Ajax? I'm curious. What do foreach-loop add in your code? ($$key = $value) ?

Comment: the php works well. I get this result displayed (replaced data by xxx):[{"Pfirstname":"xx","Plastname":"xxx","Pemail":"xx"},{"Pfirstname":"xx","Plastname":"xx","Pemail":"xxxx"},{"Pfirstname":"xx","Plastname":"xxx","Pemail":"xxxx"},{"Pfirstname":"xx","Plastname":"xxx","Pemail":"xxx"},{"Pfirstname":"xx","Plastname":"xx","Pemail":"xxx"}] which corresponds to the correct sql query result

Comment: I would like this to be displayed in the table (id="instito") on the html form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try `append` rather than `after`, try it.

**EDIT**

Please use the following function

```
var htmlStr = ""; //to store html
$(document).ready(function(){
    //// to send query to php file: for slect institution
        $("#subinst").click(function(event) {

        var url = "http://localhost/SelectPersonsBasedOnInstitution.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $("#myForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {
                   //alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                   var json_data = $.parseJSON(data);
                   var items = [];  //array
                              $.each(json_data, function(key, val) {

                            //add table rows
                                items.push('<tr border=1><td>' + json_data[key].Pfirstname + '</td><td>' + json_data[key].Plastname + '</td><td><a mailto:=" ' + json_data[key].Pemail + ' " >' + json_data[key].Pemail + '</a></td></tr>');
                            });//end each
                            //concatenate all html
                        htmlStr=items.join('');

                            //append code
                            $('#instito').append(htmlStr);
               }
             });

        event.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });

});//ready()
```

and I think you can remove the event handler `$( "#subinst" ).button().click(function( event ) {` from your script.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried and I get the same result: the php page is loaded and the JSON is displayed on it.

Comment: Did some progress: Firebug pointed a bug: I replaced $( "$subinst" ).button().click(function( event ) { by $( "#subinst" ).button().click(function( event ) {. Now I have the query result displayed in an alert message. The php is not loaded anymore. The alert message is declared in my code in fact (see above). How can I direct query result in the table instead?

Comment: @user2215691 Try the above updated code, hopefully it will work.

Comment: Just tried and the JSON keeps being displayed in an alert message. I have this alert message set up at the end of the script part in the <head>. Also I get an error message in firebug: "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e"

Comment: @user2215691, Please could you verify that the `success` callback is being called? put an alert over there. and make sure that you have removed `$( "#subinst" ).button().click(function( event )` from your code.

Comment: I keep your code and removed this code below since firebug says the php is run 2 times (which makes sense).     //// to send query to php file: for slect institution
    $("#subinst").click(function() {

    var url = "http://localhost/SelectPersonsBasedOnInstitution.php"; 

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#myForm").serialize(), 
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); .
           }
         });

    return false; 
    });
Now I am left with a bug "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e"

Comment: I pasted your code over the old one so the piece code you are referring to has disappeared. When put an alert, the result of the query is displayed in the alert message. Then the bug is listed by Firebug.

Comment: To keep things simpler, I have removed the `unnecessary` code from my answer. Please use this code. REMOVE the other event handler.

Comment: Eureka, that works perfectly fine. Thank you very much Ummar. Problem solved.